# How can i use asp net mvc code within javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code and i don't know why it doesn't replace my Content. Could you please help me?

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML = @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Action("MyAction").ToHtmlString());
    }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">myFunction</button>
<div id="Content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanna use AJAX:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $('#Content').load('@Url.Action("MyAction")');
    }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">myFunction</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

The `Html.Action` helper that you were using has a quite different purpose. It is used to render a child action. You may read the following blog post for more details: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/

Comment: Yeah, it comes bundled with ASP.NET MVC. Could be nice to take advantage of it instead of reinventing quite a lot of javascript code.